# How can I convert "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS" to a clojure inst value?

Tags: datetime, clojure, edn

Google Forms gives me this :

```
"02/12/2014 10:44:36"
```

What is a good way for converting it to edn time format using clojure?

```
;=> #inst "2014-12-02T10:44:36.000-00:00"
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

GForm is giving me hours from 0 to 23.
So, the answer should work with this:

```
"02/12/2014 15:44:36"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`clj-time`](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time):

```
(require '[clj-time.coerce :as c]
         '[clj-time.format :as f])

(def custom-formatter (f/formatter "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"))

(pr-str
 (c/to-date
  (f/parse custom-formatter "02/12/2014 10:44:36")))

; => "#inst \"2014-12-02T10:44:36.000-00:00\""
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Would it be possible to achieve this through clojure.instant library? https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.instant

Comment: No, since clojure.instant does not expect its arguments in the format that you specified.

Comment: Excellent. I'm testing the solution, but the times given from Google Forms range from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. Trying to parse `"21/11/2014 15:23:35"`gives me this error: `Value 15 for clockhourOfHalfday must be in the range [1,12]`. This can be resolved by switching `hh`to `HH` in the formatter string.